# Pymongo Error while deploying a Flask Application in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, pymongo

I am deploying my Flask application in Heroku server.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, session, redirect
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
import bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'demo'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@dsxxxxx.mlab.com:xxxxx/demo'

mongo = PyMongo(app)
```

My Flask Application runs well in my local machine. But while deploying, I receive an application Error with logs "

```
2017-02-17T19:55:08.948578+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/login_example.py", line 2, in <module>
2017-02-17T19:55:08.948578+00:00 app[web.1]:     from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
2017-02-17T19:55:08.948578+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 110, in load_module
2017-02-17T19:55:08.948579+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
2017-02-17T19:55:08.948579+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named flask.ext.pymongo
```

I already instralled the pymongo. I follow the tutorial which comes with PyMongo (Two letters are in Capitals). Can you please give me how I can solve this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because `flask.ext.pymongo`is deprecated? I got a deprecation warning on my flask app that is using pymongo. That might get rid of your import error. What I do is `from flask_pymongo import PyMongo`

Comment: Now got to find the solution. Everytime you do pip install, you have to freeze using pip freeze -requirements.txt. That solved the problem.